# Help with a multiple choice question of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So, the question is as follows:

Let $H_1=\{(x,y)|y=x\}$ and $H_2=\{(x,y)|y=-x\}$ be two subspace of a vector space $R^2(R)$. Then which of the following statement is correct?

A) $H_1+H_2$ is an improper subspace of $R^2$

B) $H_1+H_2$ is a proper subspace of $R^2$

C) $H_1+H_2$ is not a subspace of R^2

D) None of these.

My attempt: As $H_1\cap H_2$=$\{0\}$ we can write  $H_1+H_2$=$\{x+y|x\in H_1, y \in H_2\}$, so $H_1+H_2$=$\{(2x,0)\}$
So I think option B) is correct? But answer given is that A) is correct.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $(1,1)+(2,-2)$ is also in $H_1+H_2$.

Comment: Yes, so is $(3,0)$

Comment: You should learn to "feel" the answer to a question like this. The subspaces are crossed, so their sum is clearly dimension 2.

Comment: @Charles Hudgins Thank you for your advice. I got it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) is correct since every $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ can be expresed as $$(x,y) =\left(\frac{x+y}{2} ,\frac{x+y}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{x-y}{2} ,\frac{-x+y}{2}\right)\in H_1 +H_2$$

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get it. Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: this implies that $H_1 +H_2 =\mathbb{R}^2$ so $H_1 +H_2 $ is improper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Comment: Ok got it! Thank you for clarification.